# Proxy Pass exclusion

Tags: proxy

```
 <VirtualHost 172.16.0.21:80>
ServerName test.com
     DocumentRoot /usr/local/liferay/tomcat7/webapps
ErrorLog logs/error_log
CustomLog logs/default-access_log common
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /owa !
    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/star_weconnor.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/weconnor.com.key
```

SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/CA/certs/EntrustSecureServerCA.crt

Now I want to add a open webanalytics in /var/www/html/owa. So it will be : http://test.com/owa but when I access this site it looks like its being forwarded to Tomcat http 404 not found) .how to make this working